# Cross Products and charged particles in magnetic fields.

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, physics, inner-products, cross-product

**Background :** I am Fresher Mathematics Student in University. We are currently learning cross products. I am struggling with this question.

---

**Questions**

- If a charged particle of charge $q$ is travelling with a velocity $\bf v$ in a magnetic field $\bf B$, then the force that the charged particle feels is given by $$\textbf{F}=q\bf{v\times B}$$ In this case, the force $\bf F$ is also a vector quantity, since it has both the magnitude and the direction. So, the cross product plays an important role in physics and engineering.
  [image]
  Now suppose that a proton with some positive charge $q$ is travelling in the $xy$-plane with a velocity in the direction of the vector $$\textbf v = \begin{pmatrix}3\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}$$ and that the magnetic field $\bf B$ is a uniform field pointing straight up in the $z-$direction, perpendicular to the $xy-$plane. Then, Find the direction of the force that the moving proton feels.
- This
  [image]

---

**My Attempt:** I am aware that the result of the cross product of two vectors is such a vector that if I dot multiply with the either of the original vectors I get zero, Which means the cross product is perpendicular. I don't know how using that example how I can solve the problem.

I would appreciate any help in the questions. Thanks!

---

Comment: Please enter the critical parts of your problem as text instead of pasting pictures of them. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in image summaries. To boot, that first image is nigh unreadable without zooming in on the text in it. Use MathJax to format mathematical expressions; you can find a quick reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\vec{B} = \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\\ k\end{pmatrix} k>0$

Now, $\vec{F} = q\vec{v} \times \vec{B} = q\begin{pmatrix}3 \\-1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}\times\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0\\ k\end{pmatrix} = -q\begin{pmatrix}k \\ 3k\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$

> $$\hat{F} = -q\frac{k}{|q|k\sqrt{1+9}}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 3\\ 0\end{pmatrix} = \frac{-\operatorname{sgn}(q)}{\sqrt{10}}\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 3\\ 0\end{pmatrix}$$

Try taking dot products  $\vec{F}\cdot\vec{v}$ and $\vec{F}\cdot\vec{B}$

Comment: Thank you very much! That made sense and was the correct answer

Comment: You're welcome !